# Call a function on Input Completion

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage, innerhtml

I have a name input on 1.html.
I need to call a function where the input will be stored after completion, and when the person clicks ~next~ to go to the next page (2.html), whatever was stored appears there.
Example:

~1.html~

What's your name?
~input~ John ~input~

~2.html~

Hi, John! How can i help you?

I know i can use Session Storage to do it, but i'm not sure on how to proceed.
Here's what i have:

1.html

```
<p>"Whats Your Name?"</p>
<input id="your-name-input" type="text">
<a href="2.html">
   <button id="next-button">Next</button>

<script> 

nextButton = document.getElementById("next-button);

nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var name = document.getElementbyId("your-name-input").value;
  if(name !== "") {
     sessionStorage.setItem("name", name);
     } else {
    alert("Please fill yout name")
});
</script>
```

And then, on 2.html i have:

```
<p id="user-name"></p>
```

What i'm trying to do, is to put inside the `<p>`, the following greeting:
Hi (name.value), how can i help you?

How can i call a function that loads the name value on the 2.html page when the page loads?

Comment: If you want to store the input value as the user enters it, just add `oninput="setName()"` to your `input` element in 1.html

Comment: remove the value from the variable (document.getElementById("your-name-input") and add it after name variable inside the function ( localStorage.setItem("name", name.value);

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work. There are a few things missing in your code, not sure if you copied everything in.

In either case, the below works for me. You just need to update the link in the `window.location =`  syntax. When you do that, it will take your stored value to the new page in the same tab, and display it using the script code in 2.html.

Code in 1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>Your name test</title>

</head>

<body>

    <p>Whats Your Name?</p>
    <input id="your-name-input" type="text">
    <button id="next-button">Next</button>

    <script> 
        const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-button");
        const input = document.getElementById("your-name-input");
        
        nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
          const name = input.value;
          if(name !== "") {
             sessionStorage.setItem("name", name);
             window.location = "<link to your 2.html file>";
             } else {
                alert("Please fill your name")
             }
        });

    </script>
    
</body>

<footer>

</footer>
</html>
```

Code in 2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1" />
    <title>See, it works</title>

</head>

<body>

    <p id="user-name"></p>

    <script>

        const displayText = document.getElementById("user-name");
        const storedValue = sessionStorage.getItem("name");

        console.log(storedValue);

        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            displayText.innerHTML = "Hi " + storedValue;
        })

    </script>
    
</body>

<footer>

</footer>
</html>
```

**Original ans to original question:**

You could use an addEventListener with an IF statement for your 'next' button and then the code you already have for localStorage.

Depending on what you need from your page, you could also use sessionStorage - that one doesn't save the input forever so might save, albeit limited, space on your user's computer.

I don't see the HTML for your button yet. But assuming you have it, here's an option for the rest of your code in 1.html.

Inside 1.html script tag:

```
nextButton = document.getElementById("yourButtonID");


nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
   var name = document.getElementById("your-name-input").value;
   if(name !== "") { // if input is not empty
      localStorage.setItem("name", name); // set the value in localStorage
      } else {
         alert("Please fill your name")} // else, display an alert (if you like)
   });
```

Comment: Thank You! That was very helpfull! Apparently, using Session Storage would be a better option.

I still have one problem. I checked Session Storage, and the "name" value was stored there successfully, BUT, i still can't manage to get that value on 2.html.

Im trying to call that function with and "onload" on my <p>.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. How are you testing if the value comes through? The sessionStorage should work if you go from your 1.html to 2.html in the same browser tab. If you are testing on a live local browser on two different tabs, I don't think sessionStorage will work, as those are really two sessions (i.e. two tabs). If this is not it, can you update your answer with your new 2.html code?

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly! I just edited my question, using what you already told me to do, and updating it with the code i have at the moment, and what i'm struggling with.

I couldn't put the code in this comment since there's a maximum character limit.


Once again, i really appreciate all the help you've been giving so far!

Comment: I updated my answer based on this. Works for me, hopefully for you too.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly!
I`m a first timer here, so i can't give you an upvote, since i don't have enough rep yet. But i wish i could!
Thank you so much for your patience! I'm still learning, and i guess i made it very clear, lol.

Have a great day!

Comment: No worries, I happened to have just done something similar so it caught my eye. Happy it helped you. Good luck with your projects.